# #Flutter How to reset automatically a dropdown_search field after form submition

Tags: flutter, package, dropdown

I am currently working on a small flutter project where i have to submit a form. I used Dropdown_search package for the dropdown field. I want to reset the field automatically after form submition? Does any one have a solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example of the [package docs](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search/example).
They use a formkey like this: `final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();`

On this _formKey you could call  `_formKey.currentState.reset();` to reset the formfield to its initial value.

Comment: unfortunately it does not reset the dropdown_search field, i tried it

Comment: @user2783212 have you wrapped it with a setState() call and put it at the end of your submit function? Because this is how you handle flutter form fields. The package uses a clear() method behind the scenes, maybe dive into it with its GitHub Repo linked on pub.dev.